# IntelliJ-plugin Flex UI designer doesn't launch in linux

Tags: linux, apache-flex, user-interface, intellij-idea, designer

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 11.1 for linux and I installed the Flex UI Designer plugin.
But it doesn't launch. A briefly visible message says:

"AIR runtime 2.6 or later is required to launch Flex UI Designer.
 Please add the Flex SDK 4.5 or later that includes required AIR runtime to the list of 
 available SDKs. Some additional steps may be required on Linux."

The 'additional steps' hyperlinks to a documentation that does not open, thus I need your help.

The Linux is Ubuntu Precise Pengolin. The Flex version is 4.6, and AIR is installed systemwide, but there is also a subdirectory in the locally installed Flex SDK directory:

```
/runtimes/air/android
/runtimes/air/win
/runtimes/air/mac
```

What are those 'additional steps' I have to do for linux?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this is the link you were looking for: http://helpx.adobe.com/air/kb/install-32-bit-air-linux.html ? It's http://helpx.adobe.com/air/kb/install-air-2-64-bit.html for 64 bit.

Comment: Adobe AIR is already installed properly on my system. The problem seems to be that IntelliJ requires it to be installed inside the Flex SDK directory. In the IntelliJ forum (http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin?pr=idea&pluginId=5845 ) it is mentioned that /runtimes/linux must exist, and it doesn't in mine. It is nowhere mentioned how AIR should be properly installed into such a custom location. Somehow I feel like a noob, but there is not much Linux AIR support out there.

Comment: I suspect you may be running into versioning issues. Flex 4.6 is shipped w/ AIR 3.1 which is not supported on Linux.  So you either need to get the Flex 4.5 SDK--which includes AIR 2.6--or downgrade the AIR SDK in your Flex 4.6 install.  [Note: I'm unclear of Flex 4.6 is compatible w/ AIR 2.6]

Comment: Yeah, I looked into AIR 2.6 and highly doubt this would work safely with Flex 4.6, if at all. I was searching for Flex 4.5 linux in Adobe and various software archives on the net, but couldn't find except the Windows one. If anyone could provide me a download location for Linux Flex 4.5 would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download Adobe AIR 2.6 SDK Linux from http://helpx.adobe.com/air/kb/archived-air-sdk-version.html and unpack it over your Flex SDK installation.
But I'm not sure that UI Designer with AIR 2.6 will be able to show Flex 4.6 components. Probably with AIR 2.6 you'll be able to work only with Flex SDK 4.1 or 4.5.
Please answer if it helps.

Comment: I did what you say with AIR 2.6 and Flex 4.6. When I do 'Open Design View' on my main.mxml file then ErrorLog says: "Open Design View: Internal error while sorting libraries". Seems like I need to downgrade Flex. But I still could not find the download for Flex SDK 4.5 Linux.

Comment: I also downloaded http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/flex/sdk/builds/flex4.5/flex_sdk_4.5.0.20967.zip which I suppose is for windows because there was no runtimes/air/linux inside. Hence I unpacked AIR 2.6 onto this installation as well. But also when using this configuration (Flex4.5 (win?) + AIR 2.6) I get the same error message "Open Design View: Internal error while sorting libraries"

Comment: It seems this error message appears on one particular very big project of mine. With a small sample program I was able to run the Design View now.

Comment: After you get 'Internal error while sorting libraries' please create an issue in http://youtrack.jetbrains.net and attach IntelliJ IDEA logs (Help | Reveal Logs) there.